# get value of nested lists and dictionaries of a json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get value of 'description' and first 'x','y' of related to that description from a json file so I used pandas.io.json.json_normalize and followed [this example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) at end of page but getting error:
KeyError: ("Try running with errors='ignore' as key %s is not always present", KeyError('description',))

How can I get value of 'description' "Play" and  "Game" and first 'x','y' of related to that description (0,2) and (1, 2) respectively from following json file and save result as a data frame?

I edited the code and I want to get this as result:

```
   0  1     2  3
0        Play  Game    
1        
2               
3               
4
```

but Game is not in the x,y that should be.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


data = [
            {
            "responses": [
                {
                    "text": [
                        {
                            "description": "Play",
                            "bounding": {
                                "vertices": [
                                    {
                                        "x": 0,
                                        "y": 2
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 513,
                                        "y": -5
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 513,
                                        "y": 73
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 438,
                                        "y": 73
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "description": "Game",
                            "bounding": {
                                "vertices": [
                                    {
                                        "x": 1,
                                        "y": 2
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 307,
                                        "y": 29
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 307,
                                        "y": 55
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "x": 201,
                                        "y": 55
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
#w is columns h is rows
w, h = 4, 5;

Matrix = [[' ' for j in range(w)] for i in range(h)]


for row in data:
    for response in row["responses"]:
        for entry in response["text"]:
            Description = entry["description"]
            x = entry["bounding"]["vertices"][0]["x"]
            y = entry["bounding"]["vertices"][0]["y"]
            Matrix[x][y] = Description

df = pd.DataFrame(Matrix)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `data[0]['responses'][0]['text']` to json_normalize like this

```
df = json_normalize(data[0]['responses'][0]['text'],[['bounding','vertices']], 'description')
```

which will result in

```
     x   y description
0  438  -5        Play
1  513  -5        Play
2  513  73        Play
3  438  73        Play
4  201  29        Game
5  307  29        Game
6  307  55        Game
7  201  55        Game
```

I hope this is what you are expecting.

EDIT:

```
df.groupby('description').get_group('Play').iloc[0]
```

will give you the first item of a group 'play'

```
x               438
y                -5
description    Play
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: This returns all x,y of related to that description. How can I get only first x,y?